# IIS redirection rules using query string parameters

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

I want to make a not-so-common redirection on IIS and I'm not too sure this is possible.
In my case I want to do something like that:

http://www.mywebsite/app/stuff?id=123 to http://www.mywebsite/app2/stuff?id2=456

Since there is nothing in common between the 2 parameters (only a file mapping the old URL and the new one) I was planning to create manual redirection rules for each entries to be redirected.

However my first simple tests showed by that it doesn't seem to work.
[image: Test rule looks like this]

Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible? If it is, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, if you want to modify the querystring by using url rewrite, I suggest you could try to use below rule:

```
       <rule name="MatchQueryString" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="id=123" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="/app2/stuff?id2=456" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
```